# Contact session transfer on failover

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I've been reading about [contact session transfering](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/server_considerations/server_clusters_and_transferring_contact_sessions) on sc 8.2 and 9.0.1 and I'm wondering of what's the expected behaviour when Sitecore tries to transfer a session between clusters and one doesn't respond for any unforseen reason.

Suppose that Cluster A and Cluster B were exchanging sessions as usual. An Earthquake has its epicentre on Cluster B so it will be out for at least 12 hours while I rebuild the whole thing shoving the debris aside.

How would Cluster A cope with that, particularly on those initial minutes when sessions were still flagged as Cluster B sessions?